# Ionic 1 how to set footer with icons in two row

Tags: ionic-framework

Does ionic 1 have some specific directive in which i can put two rows with icons? The problem is that ion-footer has fixed height. Is it solution to type manual css?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

*Can also be a subfooter (higher up) if the ‘bar-subfooter’ class is applied* from [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionFooterBar/)

Maybe you can have an ionic footer and a ionic subfooter. If not, you will have to type manual css.